# CSOM - Field or property "QueryText" does not exist

Tags: csom, keywordquery

I am attempting to search files and folders held in SharePoint for a user entered phrase but consistently get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Field or property "QueryText" does not exist.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryToServerAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at SharePointAccessTest.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\POC\SharePointAccessTest\Program.cs:line 78
```

I am using the latest release (1.11.0) of PnP.Framework in a .NET 6 console application which uses the SharePoint client object model (CSOM).

Here's the request that is sent to SharePoint that I managed to capture via Fiddler Classic:

```http
POST https://**redacted**.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/SubSite/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery HTTP/1.1
Host: **redacted**.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer ***redacted***
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 1112

<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"><Actions><ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" /><ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3" /><ObjectPath Id="6" ObjectPathId="5" /><ObjectPath Id="8" ObjectPathId="7" /><ObjectIdentityQuery Id="9" ObjectPathId="7" /><SetProperty Id="10" ObjectPathId="7" Name="QueryText"><Parameter Type="String">test</Parameter></SetProperty><ObjectPath Id="12" ObjectPathId="11" /><Method Name="ExecuteQuery" Id="13" ObjectPathId="11"><Parameters><Parameter ObjectPathId="7" /></Parameters></Method></Actions><ObjectPaths><StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" /><Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Web" /><Property Id="5" ParentId="3" Name="Lists" /><Method Id="7" ParentId="5" Name="GetByTitle"><Parameters><Parameter Type="String">Published Documents</Parameter></Parameters></Method><Constructor Id="11" TypeId="{8d2ac302-db2f-46fe-9015-872b35f15098}" /></ObjectPaths></Request>
```

Here's the formatted XML:

```xml
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0"
    ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
    <Actions>
        <ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" />
        <ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3" />
        <ObjectPath Id="6" ObjectPathId="5" />
        <ObjectPath Id="8" ObjectPathId="7" />
        <ObjectIdentityQuery Id="9" ObjectPathId="7" />
        <SetProperty Id="10" ObjectPathId="7" Name="QueryText">
            <Parameter Type="String">test</Parameter>
        </SetProperty>
        <ObjectPath Id="12" ObjectPathId="11" />
        <Method Name="ExecuteQuery" Id="13" ObjectPathId="11">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter ObjectPathId="7" />
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
        <StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" />
        <Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Web" />
        <Property Id="5" ParentId="3" Name="Lists" />
        <Method Id="7" ParentId="5" Name="GetByTitle">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="String">Published Documents</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
        <Constructor Id="11" TypeId="{8d2ac302-db2f-46fe-9015-872b35f15098}" />
    </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

And the formatted response:

```json
[
  {
    "SchemaVersion": "15.0.0.0",
    "LibraryVersion": "16.0.23501.12002",
    "ErrorInfo": {
      "ErrorMessage": "Field or property \"QueryText\" does not exist.",
      "ErrorValue": null,
      "TraceCorrelationId": "8f13a0a0-70f0-6000-48fe-78b17a865d0d",
      "ErrorCode": -1,
      "ErrorTypeName": "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
    },
    "TraceCorrelationId": "8f13a0a0-70f0-6000-48fe-78b17a865d0d"
  }
]
```

And finally the code that I am trying to get this to work with in a .NET 6 console app. The app authenticates using client credentials (client ID and secret):

```cs
var siteUrl = $"https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/SubSite";
using var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager()
    .GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))

var documents = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Published Documents");
var query = new KeywordQuery(clientContext, documents.Path)
{
    QueryText = "test",
};

var searchResults = new SearchExecutor(clientContext).ExecuteQuery(query);

await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

I have managed to get other aspects of this working and can successfully navigate folder and files, and retrieve file contents but am really stuck with this search functionality.

I am fairly new to SharePoint development and have probably missed something that's really obvious to somebody else but I'm unable to find anything relevant to this specific error!

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis#query-using-the-net-client-object-model and this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219952/using-the-sharepoint-search-for-a-specific-library-in-csom if it helps

Comment: @GaneshSanap If I remove `documents.Path` I get the following error: `The current principal does not have permission to execute queries on behalf of other users.`.